# Exporting Gitlab activity to Github and vice-versa?

Tags: github, gitlab

I'd like to export my Gitlab account's activity to Github.

Is there any way to link those two accounts, without having to migrate the repositories ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'account activity' ? Pushes, comments ? How would it be relevant to have these in github if you repositories are not in github ?

Comment: @CCH Because I contribute to different open source projects (on GH especially) and personal projects (on GL mostly). And i'd like to gather all my activity on GH (i.e. commit activity, comments and reviews, PRs, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Github activity feed will only link to activities happening *within* GH.
If you want to have a merged view of your GH and GL activity, you'll have to merge them in a separate tool.

You could create for example a slack channel on wich both your github and gitlab repos post :
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/slack.html
- https://github.com/integrations/slack

Or if you only really want **your** activity feed, you can get both your feeds RSS links (you can find the links on your GH and GL activity pages) and merge them using a tool like this one : http://www.rssmix.com/